# How to use multiprocessing with class instances in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, decorator

I am trying to create a class than can run a separate process to go do some work that takes a long time, launch a bunch of these from a main module and then wait for them all to finish.  I want to launch the processes once and then keep feeding them things to do rather than creating and destroying processes.  For example, maybe I have 10 servers running the dd command, then I want them all to scp a file, etc.

My ultimate goal is to create a class for each system that keeps track of the information for the system in which it is tied to like IP address, logs, runtime, etc.  But that class must be able to launch a system command and then return execution back to the caller while that system command runs, to followup with the result of the system command later.

My attempt is failing because I cannot send an instance method of a class over the pipe to the subprocess via pickle.  Those are not pickleable.  I therefore tried to fix it various ways but I can't figure it out.  How can my code be patched to do this?  What good is multiprocessing if you can't send over anything useful?

Is there any good documentation of multiprocessing being used with class instances?  The only way I can get the multiprocessing module to work is on simple functions.  Every attempt to use it within a class instance has failed.  Maybe I should pass events instead?  I don't understand how to do that yet.

```
import multiprocessing
import sys
import re

class ProcessWorker(multiprocessing.Process):
    """
    This class runs as a separate process to execute worker's commands in parallel
    Once launched, it remains running, monitoring the task queue, until "None" is sent
    """

    def __init__(self, task_q, result_q):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.task_q = task_q
        self.result_q = result_q
        return

    def run(self):
        """
        Overloaded function provided by multiprocessing.Process.  Called upon start() signal
        """
        proc_name = self.name
        print '%s: Launched' % (proc_name)
        while True:
            next_task_list = self.task_q.get()
            if next_task is None:
                # Poison pill means shutdown
                print '%s: Exiting' % (proc_name)
                self.task_q.task_done()
                break
            next_task = next_task_list[0]
            print '%s: %s' % (proc_name, next_task)
            args = next_task_list[1]
            kwargs = next_task_list[2]
            answer = next_task(*args, **kwargs)
            self.task_q.task_done()
            self.result_q.put(answer)
        return
# End of ProcessWorker class

class Worker(object):
    """
    Launches a child process to run commands from derived classes in separate processes,
    which sit and listen for something to do
    This base class is called by each derived worker
    """
    def __init__(self, config, index=None):
        self.config = config
        self.index = index

        # Launce the ProcessWorker for anything that has an index value
        if self.index is not None:
            self.task_q = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
            self.result_q = multiprocessing.Queue()

            self.process_worker = ProcessWorker(self.task_q, self.result_q)
            self.process_worker.start()
            print "Got here"
            # Process should be running and listening for functions to execute
        return

    def enqueue_process(target):  # No self, since it is a decorator
        """
        Used to place an command target from this class object into the task_q
        NOTE: Any function decorated with this must use fetch_results() to get the
        target task's result value
        """
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.task_q.put([target, args, kwargs]) # FAIL: target is a class instance method and can't be pickled!
        return wrapper

    def fetch_results(self):
        """
        After all processes have been spawned by multiple modules, this command
        is called on each one to retreive the results of the call.
        This blocks until the execution of the item in the queue is complete
        """
        self.task_q.join()                          # Wait for it to to finish
        return self.result_q.get()                  # Return the result

    @enqueue_process
    def run_long_command(self, command):
        print "I am running number % as process "%number, self.name

        # In here, I will launch a subprocess to run a  long-running system command
        # p = Popen(command), etc
        # p.wait(), etc
        return 

    def close(self):
        self.task_q.put(None)
        self.task_q.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = ["some value", "something else"]
    index = 7
    workers = []
    for i in range(5):
        worker = Worker(config, index)
        worker.run_long_command("ls /")
        workers.append(worker)
    for worker in workers:
        worker.fetch_results()

    # Do more work... (this would actually be done in a distributor in another class)

    for worker in workers:
        worker.close()
```

Edit:  I tried to move the `ProcessWorker` class and the creation of the multiprocessing queues outside of the `Worker` class and then tried to manually pickle the worker instance.  Even that doesn't work and I get an error

> RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes
>   through inheritance

.  But I am only passing references of those queues into the worker instance??  I am missing something fundamental.  Here is the modified code from the main section:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = ["some value", "something else"]
    index = 7
    workers = []
    for i in range(1):
        task_q = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
        result_q = multiprocessing.Queue()
        process_worker = ProcessWorker(task_q, result_q)
        worker = Worker(config, index, process_worker, task_q, result_q)
        something_to_look_at = pickle.dumps(worker) # FAIL:  Doesn't like queues??
        process_worker.start()
        worker.run_long_command("ls /")
```

Comment: Have you seen [`dispy`](http://dispy.sourceforge.net/)? It might save a headache or two :)

Comment: I couldn't find any examples for dispy that used classes.  Everything seems to run from __main__ and that is not how I intend to use it.  My examples using multiprocessing.Process worked fine in __main__ but fail when I try to use classes and methods with state

Comment: I know this is late in the game, but if you use a fork of `multiprocessing` called `pathos.multiprocessing`, you can pickle class instances easily.  If you need to dink with the `Queue` objects and whatnot, then you can access the augmented forked `Queues` by importing `from processing import Queue`.  `pathos.multiprocessing` uses `dill`, which **does** serialize and send the class definitions along with the instances.

Comment: You can also use `dill` and `pathos.multiprocessing` to send a class method (bound or unbound).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of attempting to send a method itself (which is impractical), try sending a *name* of a method to execute.

Provided that each worker runs the same code, it's a matter of a simple `getattr(self, task_name)`.

I'd pass tuples `(task_name, task_args)`, where `task_args` were a dict to be directly fed to the task method:

```
next_task_name, next_task_args = self.task_q.get()
if next_task_name:
  task = getattr(self, next_task_name)
  answer = task(**next_task_args)
  ...
else:
  # poison pill, shut down
  break
```

Comment: That doesn't work...I get the error "AttributeError: 'ProcessWorker' object has no attribute 'run_long_command'".  I wouldn't expect that to work since ProcessWorker has none of the methods that exist in the Worker class.  I want to send the method over the pipe (with state information) so that the remote process can make use of all of that state information.  I really don't see the point of the multiprocess module if all it will do is run stateless function on the other side.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to repeat. You _can not_ send a method over the pipe. This is why `pickle` complains about it. Sending executable code is not impossible, but it gets _much_ more involved that just deserializing a code object. You should implement the methods you want to run in Worker class beforehand. If you do need to send code not know in advance, your best bet is sending Python source as a string, then calling `compile` and `eval` on it. If you want to send a method with a state, put all the state into method's arguments, or use a shared database.

Comment: WRT running stateless methods: you have pipes that can hold the state. You parcel out your initial state to several processes, then collect the results back. If you want highly shared state (e.g. geometry for ray tracing), you use an (in-memory) database, anything from memcached to a regular RDBMS. Using global _mutable_ state is usually a bad enough idea. If you have to, use an arbiter process that reads from pipes and resolves conflicts (e.g. a database).

Comment: When I launch a child process, is it a copy of the parent process?  I do not need compile unknown code, I just need to figure out how to invoke the copy that exists in the new process.  I didn't think I could have my own functions in the ProcessWorker class, based on online examples I found.

Comment: Thanks 9000 for your help on this.  Your responses definitely sent me down the correct path to help me solve this!

Answer (score 30):

So, the problem was that I was assuming that Python was doing some sort of magic that is somehow different from the way that C++/fork() works.  I somehow thought that Python only copied the class, not the whole program into a separate process.  I seriously wasted days trying to get this to work because all of the talk about pickle serialization made me think that it actually sent everything over the pipe.  I knew that certain things could not be sent over the pipe, but I thought my problem was that I was not packaging things up properly.

This all could have been avoided if the Python docs gave me a 10,000 ft view of what happens when this module is used.  Sure, it tells me what the methods of multiprocess module does and gives me some basic examples, but what I want to know is what is the "Theory of Operation" behind the scenes!  Here is the kind of information I could have used.  Please chime in if my answer is off.  It will help me learn.

When you run start a process using this module, the whole program is copied into another process.  But since it is not the "`__main__`" process and my code was checking for that, it doesn't fire off yet another process infinitely.  It just stops and sits out there waiting for something to do, like a zombie.  Everything that was initialized in the parent at the time of calling multiprocess.Process() is all set up and ready to go.  Once you put something in the multiprocess.Queue or shared memory, or pipe, etc. (however you are communicating), then the separate process receives it and gets to work.  It can draw upon all imported modules and setup just as if it was the parent.  However, once some internal state variables change in the parent or separate process, those changes are isolated.  Once the process is spawned, it now becomes your job to keep them in sync if necessary, either through a queue, pipe, shared memory, etc.

I threw out the code and started over, but now I am only putting one extra function out in the `ProcessWorker`, an "execute" method that runs a command line.  Pretty simple.  I don't have to worry about launching and then closing a bunch of processes this way, which has caused me all kinds of instability and performance issues in the past in C++.  When I switched to launching processes at the beginning and then passing messages to those waiting processes, my performance improved and it was very stable.

BTW, I looked at this link to get help, which threw me off because the example made me think that methods were being transported across the queues:  http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/multiprocessing/communication.html
The second example of the first section used "next_task()" that appeared (to me) to be executing a task received via the queue.

Comment: As noted in my comment on your question, if you want to pickle a class instance w/o worrying about dependencies as much… you should use `dill`, which can both pickle a class definition with the class instance, *or* pickle the source code and dependencies for most objects, including user defined classes.  The fork of `multiprocessing` (mentioned in comment on question) uses `dill` for serialization… thus avoiding most of the issues you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

REF: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14179779

*Answer on Jan 6 at 6:03 by David Lynch* is not factually correct when he says that he was misled by
http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/multiprocessing/communication.html.

The code and examples provided are correct and work as advertised. `next_task()` **is** executing a task received via the queue -- try and understand what the `Task.__call__()` method is doing.

In my case what, tripped me up was syntax errors in my implementation of `run()`. It seems that the sub-process will not report this and just fails silently -- leaving things stuck in weird loops! Make sure you have some kind of syntax checker running e.g. Flymake/Pyflakes in Emacs.

Debugging via `multiprocessing.log_to_stderr()`F helped me narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Other than serialize objects or inherit a parent class like this:

```
class MyClass(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, arg, queue):
        super(MyClass).__init__()
        self.arg = arg
        self.queue = queue
    def run(self):
        while True:
            _ = queue.get()
```

We can remove some code from MyClass and add an intermediary start method outside the class namespace that asks the same arguments as MyClass and that creates the instance before running it:

```
def start_my_class(arg, queue):
    my_class = MyClass(arg, queue)
    my_class.run()

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, arg, queue):
        self.arg = arg
        self.queue = queue
    def run(self):
        while True:
            _ = queue.get()
```

Then we can create the Process instance and run it from the parent by writing:

```
worker = multiprocessing.Process(target=start_my_class,  args=(arg, queue,))
worker.start()
```