# mysql connector in a separate python process, cannot pickle in constructor / __init__

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, multiprocessing, pickle

I want to put some SQL db processing (when some items are received a batch is written) in a separate process in python (currently I have a main thread that spawns another callback handle thread to process data that is received from the internet by yet another reader thread - IB TWS API for the ones interested)

```
class sqlExecutor(multiprocessing.Process):

  conn = None
  cursor = None

  def __init__(self, task_queue):
    multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
    self.task_queue = task_queue
    
    self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
      host="192.168.10.10",
      user="homestead",
      password="secret",
      database="xxxxx"
    )

    self.cursor = self.conn.cursor() 

  def run(self):
    batch = []
    while True:
      row = self.task_queue.get()
      if row is None: 
        self.task_queue.task_done()
        break
      # task complete for join function
      self.task_queue.task_done()
      if len(batch) == 4:
        # write to db
        insert_sql_query = """
        INSERT IGNORE INTO tickvalues (contractid, dttm, value, tickType)
        VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s )
        """
        self.cursor.executemany(insert_sql_query, batch)
        self.conn.commit()
        batch.clear()
                    
      batch.append(row)

  def __del__(self):
      self.cursor.close()
      self.conn.close()
```

The app.run() (which derives from EWrapper, EClient) contains:

```
    ...
    now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    conId = self.contractList[reqId].conId

    # send tuple to the other process
    item = (conId, now, price, tickType)
    self.tasks.put(item)
    ...
```

Part of run() that is part of the data processing thread and is started from main thread, e.g.,

```
  thread_app = threading.Thread(target=app.run)
  thread_app.start()
```

This is the main thread:

```
def main():
  app = BasicApp() 
  app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, 0)

  tasks = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()

  sqlTickSaver = sqlExecutor(tasks)

  sqlTickSaver.start()

  app.tasks = tasks
  ...
```

When running it gives me 'TypeError: cannot pickle 'SSLSocket' object'. But I read some suggestions elsewhere that I should put the mysql connector completely in the process itself/constructor (which I did as far as I know). Besides, I send only tuples via the queue (and according Python's documentation I should be able to pickle/serialize that type).

What would be a solution? When leaving out the mysql things in init that error dissappears (but something else goes wrong so I guess it has something to with mysql connector).

Comment: When I move self.conn = ... and self.cursor = ... to just before 'while True:' in def run(self): it seems to work. If anyone has a suggestion why I cannot create a mysql connection within the Process' constructor? I am very curious.

Comment: Somehow the Process' constructor does not like it when using these mysql.connector.connect related things in it. A normal class does accept it.

Comment: I think the mysql object must be somehow pickled during __init__ but not when it is in the run() method.

Comment: I found out that the constructor runs in the main process, so when it tries to spawn/duplicate the process in start() which starts _popen/run(), something goes wrong with the sql object which cannot be pickled/transferred. I assume when all is created in run() the sql connection is created in the subprocess itself and therefore no need to copy/refer it. That's my theory for now. Some info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169550/how-to-use-multiprocessing-with-class-instances-in-python